# How to upload image using ckeditor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in CodeIgniter PHP. Using ckeditor how can I upload image? Image upload button is on but image cannot upload in server. Browse server button is not working.
 In my projects ckeditor & ckfinder are in - scripts/ckeditor & scripts/ckfinder folder.

My code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
    filebrowserUploadUrl : 'scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
 });

   CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
</script>
```

in ckfinder folder inside config.php file I change this:

```
$baseUrl = '/scripts/ckfinder/userfiles/';
$enabled = true;
$config['SecureImageUploads'] = false;
```

In view page:

```
<textarea name="content_longdetails" required="1"  tabindex="4" placeholder="Content Long Details" name="ckeditor" id="ckeditor" cols="80"></textarea> <?php echo display_ckeditor($check_editor['ckeditor']); ?>
```

now what I do to upload image?